# The value is getting passed after second click- Clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to copy the URL to clipboard but that is happening only after second click

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
  var clipboard = new Clipboard('#sharePdf') //This is getting hit when clicked second time, I need it along with copyURL
  }

$('#sharePdfLink').on('click', function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: '',
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: ''
  })
    .success(function(resp) {
    var copyURL = "localhost:9191"
    $('#sharePdf').attr('data-clipboard-text', copyURL);
    $('#sharePdf').attr('data-clipboard-action', 'copy');

  }
    });
```